# Adding symbols to an image

Tags: diagrams

[image]

I'd like to add some math symbols to that picture. How can I make it? (I'm using another software to make the pics.)

Comment: Does this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/32374 help you? If not, you'll need to provide some more information :-)

Comment: Related?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's the same as linking darthbith's suggestion.

Comment: @Alenanno I see that now.  Didn't realize itself was marked a duplicate.

Comment: @Oshnaj Look at `overpic` package.  Documentation at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/overpic/opic-abs.pdf.  If more assistance in needed than post a MWE so assistance can be more efficient.

Comment: Then, as @darthbith said, you need to provide more information. That example explains how to annotate an image using TikZ. You want to annotate an image. So it seems to be a duplicate. Only you know why it isn't ;).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes No problem. :D But you're both right, I think this is an instance of "drawing over an existing image" so those questions apply. If the OP thinks they do not, then we need more details.

Comment: @Alenanno Agreed.  Based on the info currently provided, I can't distinguish the intent from the referenced questions.

Comment: Awesome, overpic worked absolutely nice! It wasn't a duplicate, though.

Comment: @Oshnaj That goes to show that we were right that it's a duplicate. :)

Comment: If a different problem can be expressed in another way and then solved, then it is indeed a duplicate. Comes up all the time in complexity theory. That said, which piece of software are you using to draw your figures? (a) looks nice (b) that software might integrate with LaTeX if it's designed to produce figures such as this.

Comment: @Alenanno No, it ain't. I won't waste my time asking the same question twice since all of my questions have been greatly solved.

Comment: @Sean I'm using CorelDraw X5.

Comment: Last time I used Corel, it was [Corel PHOTO-PAINT 5](http://s.ecrater.com/stores/239962/4f20631f73ac0_239962b.jpg) :) Crazy how time flies. You might be interested in [LaTeX in CorelDRAW](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80234/17423).

Comment: Interesting, if that works to me, you deserve a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I use Inkscape. It generate this code (and you must call it instead of image):

```
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{477.88bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.49522056)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{fig/car.pdf}}%
    \put(0.96548473,0.04397513){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$x(t)$}}}%
    \put(0.02012794,0.44631517){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$r[x(t)]$}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Look this part:

```
  \begin{picture}(1,0.49522056)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{fig/car.pdf}}%
    \put(0.96548473,0.04397513){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$x(t)$}}}%
    \put(0.02012794,0.44631517){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$r[x(t)]$}}}%
  \end{picture}%
```

Is very easy to understand:

1. Include the imagine (in my case `fig/car.pdf`).
2. Add all the TeX boxes (and so Math, too) that you need.

In Inkscape I write only some letters, for references, after I reedit the code with LaTeX function.