# \mathbb in Coreldraw

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

**Issue:** I have installed the LaTeX plugin in Coreldraw X6 from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80234/latex-in-coreldraw) and everything works perfectly except for the $\mathbb R^n$ command. Whenever I type it the plugin doesn't compile.

**Question:**

> 1) Is there a command I should write in so that the plugin read the package amsmath? For instance, I've tried

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
 $\mathbb R^n$
```

and nothing happened.

> 2) Is there any fix to this issue? Or command I should write in the plugin Macro?

Comment: to use `\mathbb`, `amsmath` is not enough (actually, it's not needed for this).  you need `\usepackage{amsfonts}`.

Comment: I see, how do I use it though? I've tried to type this in the command box and nothing.

Comment: sorry, i'm not a coreldraw user, so i can't even make a guess as to how this might be done. i did assume that since `\usepackage{amsmath}` was accepted (according to the statement of your question), substituting `\usepackage{amsfonts}` might work.  with luck, someone else here might have an answer.