# How to produce CorelDraw file from LaTeX?

Tags: pdf

It is possible to produce CorelDraw file (instead of PDF) by LaTeX? One of my publishers for some reason can't accept my book in PDF and asking for CorelDraw. I don't really know why and trying to find a way to create that file.

Comment: Have you seen [LaTeX in CorelDRAW](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80234/latex-in-coreldraw)? Maybe it could be helpful.

Comment: Find out, what his issue with PDF is. Maybe we can solve that. Otherwise probably easier to find another publisher than doing complicated stuff with a whole book?